# How to switch GPS state just like "Quick Settings" does?

Tags: android

I would like to switch the GPS status in my application. The method I know is to modify the secure setting of device like the following code

```
Settings.Secure.putString(resolver, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED, newAllowedProviders);
```

However, modifying secure setting is only available in the full rooted devices. If not, it will throw exceptions, even I have add this permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to secure settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

Recently, I discovery an open source application "Quick settings" is able to do it on an non full rooted device, however the author did not release the code of this part. The reason is that he is using some kind of android exploits, he is not willing to release it.

Does any body know how he achieve it?

---

The method that quick settings released is the same method above (modify the security setting). It works, but only in the full rooted device.

However, the real method that quick setting currently used is not released in it's source code, which could work on both root and unroot phone.

Comment: I think it's a pretty bad idea to intentionally violate system security using such an exploit (not to mention that it seems pretty likely that Google would patch such exploits in future Android releases, breaking your app). Why does your app need to change GPS settings without the user's approval?

Comment: My application is just an auto-profile application. I would like to let user to change the system settings they want automatically. I have also added the security write permission into it already.

Comment: I think is a really hard question... only "Quick Setting" could do that as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source for Quick Setting is available. You may want to build it agains API level 6. I build it agains 7 and gps toggle will not work. Let us know if you can build for 6 and see that it work on 7 or later.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the method that quick settings released is the method I mentioned (modify the security setting). It works, but only in the full rooted device. However, the real method that quick setting currently used is not released in it's source code, which could work on a unroot phone.

Comment: I think the author of Quick Setting built the app using 2.0 SDK which allow the same code to toggle gps on and off. I compile his source against 2.1 / 2.2 and the gps toggle will not work.

currently, the 2.0/2.0.1 sdk is obsolete and cannot be downloaded, so I can't build against it. If you happen to have the old sdk components, try it. Otherwise, we're out of luck.